# проблемы с ПК после использования #pragma warning в Visual studio

Tags: c++

Я ради эксперимента использовал #pragma warning, чтобы обойти ошибку с устаревшей функцией strncpy() после запуска проекта консоль закрылась без ошибок, а после я не мог провести сборку проекта повторно. Мне выдавалась ошибка LNK1168. Я перезагрузил ПК. Он запускался очень долго и у меня слетели обои рабочего стола. Так же при загрузке стола на какое-то время появилась консоль. Может ли это как-то быть связ

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скорее это проблемы после хождения на сомнительные сайты.

Comment: Проблема с ошибкой решилась. Но всё таки интересно могло ли это повлиять на загрузку ПК и насколько или проблема в чём-то другом?

Comment: @user7860670 Раньше всё было нормально, а сегодня я весь день читал Страуструпа и практиковался в коде, поэтому вряд ли, но не могу исключать такого. Хотя у меня стоит антивирус

Comment: Не читайте Страуструпа перед обедом.

Comment: @user7860670 Да я бы не сказал, что он очень сложно пишет. Вникать долго, но аппетит особо не портит. Ладно, думаю раз проблема решено, то всё нормально

Comment: [lnk1168](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1168?view=msvc-170) закончилось место на диске (сыпется?) или антивирус плохой

Comment: @KoVadim антивирус avast базовый, место на диске есть. До этого были проблемы с жёстким диском, но я их подправил через одну прогу, но вполне возможно, что ему не долго осталось

Comment: то есть, у Вас сошлись звезди. Но падающий диск это может быть причина всех бед. но аваст лучше снести от греха подальше.